# SQL Server Not releasing memory in C#

Tags: sql

We are importing data in sql using bulk copy in C#.

SQL Server is not releasing the memory even if the application exits.

We are importing data in a batch of 100000. The total number of records is around 10 million.

Please let us know how we can free/clear the sql server memory.

Below is our code.

```
 try
        {

            using (SqlConnection SQlConn = new SqlConnection(Common.SQLConnectionString))
            {                   
                DataTable dt1 = FillEmptyDateFields(dtDestination);

                //SqlTableCreator ObjTbl = new SqlTableCreator(SQlConn);

                //ObjTbl.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;

                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(SQlConn,SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock,null))
                {

                    //bulkCopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(SQlConn);
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = dt1.Rows.Count; // Batch Size Added.
                    Logger.Log("DATATABLE FINAL :" + dt1.Rows.Count.ToString(), Logger.LogType.Info);
                    if (SQlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed || SQlConn.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
                        SQlConn.Open();
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt1);
                    SQlConn.Close();
                    SQlConn.Dispose();
                    bulkCopy.Close();
                    if (bulkCopy != null)
                    {
                        ((IDisposable)bulkCopy).Dispose();
                    }                        
                }
                dt1.Dispose(); 
                dt1 = null;                           
            }

            dtDestination.Dispose();
            System.GC.Collect();
            dtDestination = null;                

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex, Logger.LogType.Error);
            throw ex;

        }
        finally 
        {

        }
```

Comment: Side note: typically `System.GC.Collect();` does more harm than good. If you are really really sure you need it you should remove it.

Comment: Side note 2: Change `throw ex;` to `throw;` otherwise you loose your stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is designed to cache as much as it is allowed to. You can adjust this limit in SQL Server configuration.

If you really want to clear the SQL Server cache you could run the SQL command

[`DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx)

Comment: @Abin : Thanks. From where exactly we can set the cache.Also Will it create any problem by running that command through C# ?

Comment: @User87 Management studio, right click on server, properties, Memory tab.

Comment: @Abin : Thanks.If our machine RAM is 4GB what should we set in MAX Memory field ?

Comment: @User87 depends on what else you have on the machine. If it is a dedicated database server you can leave it at max. If you have other things running at the machine, you need to try different sizes to give enough RAM left to your other applications.

Comment: @Abin: Thanks we will set and check.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will grow its memory consumption as it needs it. It might not necessarily release it when it is done with the specific operation that required it to allocate more RAM.

Answer (score -1):

```
Create Proc  [dbo].[MP_Rpt_ConfigureMemory]
(  @Mode  bit  )
as
declare @RAM as integer
declare @MAX as integer
declare @MIN as integer

set @RAM = 
(SELECT

      [physical_memory_in_bytes]/1048576 AS [RAM (MB)]

FROM  [sys].[dm_os_sys_info] )

Set @MAX = ((@RAM / 4) * 3) 
Set @MIN = ((@RAM / 4) * 1) 

if @Mode=0
begin
      exec SP_Configure 'min server memory', 1
      RECONFIGURE
      exec SP_Configure 'max server memory', 100
      RECONFIGURE
end
else
if @Mode = 1
begin
      exec SP_Configure 'max server memory', @MAX
      RECONFIGURE
      exec SP_Configure 'min server memory', @MIN
      RECONFIGURE
end
```

Comment: >teeth gritting> Please format that answer .... **now** (as I already mentioned in your other anser: do.not.mix.text.and.code - downvoted as an incentive to remove those leading spaces.

Comment: @kleopatra , i'm so sorry but i did not get your mean :(

Comment: see my comment to your other answer ... hint: no need to remove the explaining text (in fact, you shouldn't) - simply remove the leading _spaces_ And be sure to read the formatting help.